# how to use loop in NSMutableArray for get object at any index

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, for-loop

I have json file like this:

```
{ "fileContent" : [ { "created" : "2013/04/11 - 10:00",
    "ext" : "sql",
    "modified" : "2013/04/11 - 10:00",
    "name" : "directorffdsgfg",
    "size" : "1577",
    "type" : "file"
  },
  { "created" : "2013/04/11 - 12:10",
    "ext" : "sql",
    "modified" : "2013/04/11 - 12:10",
    "name" : "directory02",
    "size" : "1577",
    "type" : "file"
  },
  { "created" : "2013/04/11 - 12:10",
    "ext" : "zip",
    "modified" : "2013/04/11 - 12:10",
    "name" : "jquery-mousewheel-master",
    "size" : "5213",
    "type" : "file"
  }
],
"files" : 9,
"folderContent" : [ { "created" : "2013/04/11 - 05:04",
    "ext" : "sql",
    "modified" : "2013/04/11 - 05:04",
    "name" : "Folder 2",
    "size" : "1577",
    "type" : "folder"
  },
  { "created" : "2013/04/15 - 09:08",
    "ext" : "zip",
    "modified" : "2013/04/15 - 09:08",
    "name" : "Folder 1",
    "size" : "11867",
    "type" : "folder"
  }
],
"folders" : 2
}
```

I want get from top json only name value in file content and store in object. but I cant.

this is my code:

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "Object.h"
@implementation ViewController
{
    NSDictionary *titles;   //this variable for read json
    NSMutableData *Data;
    NSMutableArray *fileContent;
    NSString *janatan;
    NSString *number;
    NSInteger num;
    NSMutableArray *recipes;
}

@synthesize Table;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    Data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [Data appendData:theData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    titles = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:Data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    fileContent = [titles objectForKey:@"fileContent"];
    //NSLog(@"%@",fileContent);
    number = [titles objectForKey:@"files"];
    num = [number integerValue];
    NSLog(@"num : %d",num);
    for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%d",i);
        Object *obji = [Object new];

// this method should read many names in fileContent but not worke!!!
        janatan = [[fileContent objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"];

        NSLog(@"%@",janatan);
        obji.nameLable = janatan; 
        if(!recipes){
            recipes = [NSMutableArray array];
        }
        [recipes addObject:janatan];
        NSLog(@"object : %@",recipes);
    }

    [Table reloadData];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The Connection has been LOST" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [errorView show];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.105/janatan/root/developers/api/filemanager.php?key=5147379269&getlist=root"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return num;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: Your problem about JSON or NSMultableArray?

Comment: Where does the `mamal` object that you add to your `recipes` array come from? That doesn't appear anywhere else in your code. Apart from that, `num` seems to be `9` with your JSON data, but you only have 3 elements in your `fileContent` array...

Answer (score 2):

Replace `for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++)` 
to:

```
for (NSDictionary* dict in fileContent) {
    .......
    janatan = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
    ....... 
}
```